# Work out percentage of change done by one person on MediaWiki

Tags: php, mediawiki

I would like to work out the percentage of editing/change that one person has done to one article, so I can send out donations accordingly.

How do I do this automatically? (preferably in PHP)

Comment: Have you ever seen the mediawiki-database schema? There's a table which contains the information you need. You could pull out what you need with a SQL statement without coding a single line in PHP.

Comment: could you please hint at or show me the SQL code I'll need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editing history is stored in the `revision` table. If you have the page-id you can get the percentage of user edits by page (just replace the 1 with the page-id):

```
SELECT
    rev_user, rev_user_text,
    count(*) as rev_user_count,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM revision WHERE rev_page = 1) as rev_total_count,
    100 * count(*)/(SELECT count(*) FROM revision WHERE rev_page = 1) as rev_percent
FROM revision
WHERE rev_page = 1
GROUP BY rev_user
```

Comment: Just wait for me to check it then I'll select it as the answer. I trust it will, though :). Thanks.

Comment: Works like a charm. Just had to change `revision` to `mw_revision`, probs because of my godaddy setup.